# Sliding Vs Tumbling Windows

Tags: streaming

I'm reading a long article about Data Stream Management, and I'm a bit confused by the difference between Sliding and Tumbling Windows. So far I've understood that tumbling windows can be time-based and has fixed (start,end)-points which "tumbles" when that window expires. E.g. A time-based window can be 1 minute long. So for every minute the window tumbles to process aggregations for a data set.

It is sliding windows that gets confused me. Is sliding windows like count-based such that a window tumbles when x-number of tuples have entered the window. Or is it that the x-recent tuples that entered the window will be part of the window, and that the older tuples will be evicted from that window. I.e. a window that is continuously updated as new tuples arrives?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

1. **Tumbling** repeats at a non-overlapping interval.
2. **Hopping** is simlar to tumbling, but hopping generally has an overlapping interveral.
3. **Time Sliding** triggers at regular interval.
4. **Eviction Sliding** triggers on a count.

Below is a graphical representation showing different types of **D**ata **S**tream **M**anagement **S**ystem (**DSMS**) window - tumbling, hopping, timing policy sliding, and eviction policy(count) sliding.  I used the above example to create the image (making assumptions).

[image: Windowing in DSMS]

Comment: Thank you for creating the visual demonstration! Love it.

Answer (score 21):

**Tumbling windows (TW)**
All tuples within the window expires at the same time.

**Sliding windows (SW)**
Only some of the tuples expires at a given time

**Example**
If you have a window containing the following integers entered (Notation integer (seconds since entered)) and let's say the TW was created 60 s ago, and the time limit for both windows is 60s.

```
1 (0s), 2 (10s), 4 (24s), 8 (17s), 16 (40s)
```

Say that 20 seconds passes and then the following integers enters the window.

```
7, 3, 6
```

Now the previous TW will have expired and will only contain the values above. While the SW will contain the following values

```
7, 3, 6, 1, 2, 4, 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's think the windowing functions as a traditional [GROUP BY](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) operation which works on the time-based input data, applies a given aggregation function and outputs the result.

The key difference between a **Tumbling Window (TW)** operation and a **Sliding Window (SW)** one consists in the intersection set of the considered data points, which is empty in the former case and likely non-empty in the latter case.

A very good [reading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-window-functions) from Microsoft Azure Stream Analytics makes the difference with illustrations.

- **TW**, considering a tick of 10s such windowing operation outputs every tick the result from the aggregation function for such time frame;
- **SW**, considering a tick of Xs such windowing operation outputs every tick the result from the aggregation function for a Ys time frame *whenever an event occurs*, for instance `X = 1` and `Y = 10` then every second the windowing function is looking back ten seconds discarding systematically the oldest data point.

Let's look at a concrete example for a the following time series:

```
t0-> 5 7 4 3 1 1 3 t10-> 4 5 8 1 2 3 3 3 5 7 7 t20-> t30-> 3 3 4 t40->
```

Considering `SUM` as aggregation function and the banal strategy of SW which is the **Hoping Window (HW)**:

- at `t0` `SW = TW = 0`;
- at `t10` `SW = TW = 24`;
- at `t11` there's no TW but `SW = 23` and the intersection among successive windows is `7 4 3 1 1 3`;
- at `t11` there's no TW but `SW = 21` and the intersection among successive windows is `4 3 1 1 3 4`;
- at `t20` `TW = SW = 48`;
- at `t21` there's no TW but `SW = 44` and the intersection among successive windows is `5 8 1 2 3 3 3 5 7 7`
- at `t30` `TW = SW = 0`;
- at `t31` there's no TW but `SW = 3` and the intersection among successive windows is empty as no events occurred in `[t20, t30]`.

Another [good reading](https://softwaremill.com/windowing-in-big-data-streams-spark-flink-kafka-akka/) by SoftwareMill CTO Adam Warski which exemplifies using modern streaming technologies like Spark, Flink, Akka and Kafka.

Answer (score 0):

- **Tumbling Window:**

A tumbling window represents a consistent, disjoint time interval in the data stream. For example, if you set it to a thirty-second tumbling window, the elements with timestamp values [0:00:00-0:00:30) are in the first window. Elements with timestamp values [0:00:30-0:01:00) are in the second window.

- **Sliding or Hopping Window:**

A Sliding or hopping window represents a consistent time interval in the data stream. Sliding windows can overlap, whereas tumbling windows are disjoint. For example, a sliding window can start every thirty seconds and capture one minute of data. The frequency with which sliding windows begin is called the period. This example has a one-minute window and a thirty-second period.

**Reference:**
https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/streaming-pipelines